# Creating an xml file

Tags: php, xml, fopen, fwrite

I am trying to create an xml file and write codes inside it. But the thing is, I have to cut it in 3 sections because the middle part of the code is in loop. So far, this is what my codes looks like.

**EDIT**

This is the output I want

```
<download serverurl='http://localhost/files'>
    <file filename='image1.PNG' md5='b45110dd47aa28f8400295ec70e6b0ef'/>
    <file filename='image2.jpg' md5='3a3b3f573682ab177939b748c4623db0'/>
    <file filename='image3.jpg' md5='deaee69864bedcd5c60af3bb46b47edc'/>
```

What I always receive.

```
           <file filename='image2.jpg' md5='3a3b3f573682ab177939b748c4623db0'/>
    <file filename='image3.jpg' md5='deaee69864bedcd5c60af3bb46b47edc'/>
<download serverurl='http://localhost/files'>              
 <file filename='image1.PNG' md5='b45110dd47aa28f8400295ec70e6b0ef'/>
</download>
```

the output I am getting is pretty much random.

**END OF EDIT**

```
public function download_package1(){
    $form = $this->getUserData();

    $serverurl = "<download serverurl='http://222.127.182.57/file'>";

    file_put_contents('download.xml', $serverurl, FILE_APPEND);
}

public function download_package_images ($filename){
    $form = $this->getUserData();

    $images = "
    <file filename='".$filename."' md5='".md5_file($filename)."'/>";

    file_put_contents('download.xml', $images, FILE_APPEND);

    //THIS IS FUNCTION IS IN LOOP. THERE ARE THE FILENAMES OF THE IMAGES   UPLOADED
}

public function download_package_end (){
    $form = $this->getUserData();

    $end = "
</download>";

    file_put_contents('download.xml', $end, FILE_APPEND);
```

BUT I the order is not fixed. I already tried the `fopen/fopen` but the same thing happens. I really don't know how i could explain this, but i hope i made sense. If anyone could please help me, I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the result you receive and result you are expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than build XML by hand, use a xml-parser:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string("<download />");
$xml->addAttribute('serverurl', 'http://localhost/files');

for ($i = 0;$i < 3; $i++) 
{
    $file = $xml->addChild('file');
    $file->addAttribute('filename', "image$i.png");
    $file->addAttribute('md5', 'whateverhash');    
}  

$xml->asXML('filename.xml');
```

see it working: https://eval.in/104654